# Can grad school admission recommendation letters be generic for all applications?

Tags: graduate-admissions

Can grad school admission recommendation letters be generic for all applications? (2 or 3, not more than that).

Does it has to be specific to each school ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recommendation letters generally do not need to be tailored for each school. Admissions committee members are faculty too, and in an age where people regularly apply to 10+ programs they understand the undue burden this would place on already busy faculty.

Occasionally a more tailored letter may have some advantages, for example if the recommender has close connections at one of the programs, but it is definitely not expected or required.